# IP-Cam Wireless N Adapter Error SIOCGIFINDEX: No such device

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, webcam

I'n trying to set up an IP Cam with alternative Firmware, but can´t find Wi-Fi Net Adapter.

How to find and configure it with this hardware?

- OS: OpenIPC
- Cam: Jennov, P31
- Wireless Net Adapter: AltoBeam 6012B, USB on board Chip.
- LAN: No
- USB: No
- lshw and rfkill commands are not available.
- SSH: Yes, PuTTY
- root: Yes.

Comment: AltoBeam has poor or nonexistent Linux support. And OpenIPC isn't a normal Linux distro. If it doesn't have the driver already it's almost impossible to install it manually so, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a xiongmai camera.

Work in progress driver - https://github.com/OpenIPC/atbm_60xx

For now you have to use binary modules ripped from original firmware image - https://github.com/OpenIPC/wiki/blob/master/en/wifi-xm530.md

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).